# How to delete file from code?

Tags: file, axapta, delete-file, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to delete a *File* from X++ code.

I used this code in my method :

```
TextIO textIO;

str filename, fileOpen, folder;
int handle;
Io thisMYFile;
FileIoPermission perm;

#File
#avifiles
#OCCRetryCount

[handle, filename]  =   WINAPI::findFirstFile(folder + "\\*.csv");

fileOpen = strFmt (folder + "\\" +  filename);

perm = new FileIoPermission(fileOpen, 'w');
perm.assert();

thisMYFile = new CommaTextIo(fileOpen , 'w');

 WinApi::deleteFile(fileOpen);
}

}
 catch
{}
}
```

The Value fileOpen is : *C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\myFolder\myFile.csv* .

I can read and fill the table, but when I have to delete it, it errors with the

> catch(Exception::CLRError)

(in classes\WinAPI\DeleteFile).

Is there a permission problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have the file open via your `thisMYFile` variable.
Set it to `null` before trying to delete the file:

```
...
perm = new FileIoPermission(fileOpen, 'w');
perm.assert();

thisMYFile = new CommaTextIo(fileOpen , 'w');
// Do stuff
thisMYFile = null;

WinApi::deleteFile(fileOpen);
...
```

Comment: Beware the WinAPI functions works in client only. It will not work in batch.

Comment: Use `WinAPIServer::deleteFile(...)` if in batch and it should work.